# Conditionally count values on multiple variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df as follows and I would like to count all the "yes"(s)

```
have = data.frame(x1 = c("yes", "no", NA, "yes", "yes", "yes", NA, "no"),
                  x2 = c("no", "yes", "no", NA, "no", "yes", NA, NA),
                  x3 = c(NA, NA, NA, "yes", "yes", "yes", NA, "yes"),
                  x4 = c("no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", NA, "no"),
                  x5 = c(NA, "no", "no", "no", "no", NA, NA, "no"))

want = data.frame(have,
                  count_yes = c(1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1))
```

Here is my attempt!

```
attempt = as.data.frame(
  have %>% 
    mutate(count_yes_all = str_count(x1, "yes", na.rm=TRUE) +
             str_count(x2, "yes", na.rm=TRUE) + 
             str_count(x3, "yes", na.rm=TRUE) + 
             str_count(x4, "yes", na.rm=TRUE) + 
             str_count(x5, "yes", na.rm=TRUE))
  )
```

Two things:

1. How can I deal with NA(s)?
2. I have over 20 variables that start with "x", rather than having to write the code over 20 lines, how could I write the code more productively?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `rowSums` and `na.rm = TRUE` to deal with NAs.

If you want to specify your columns (e.g. all columns that starts with "x"), use `across` instead of `.`, e.g. `across(starts_with("x"))`, or `across(x1:x5)`.

```r
have %>% 
  mutate(count_yes = rowSums(. == "yes", na.rm = TRUE))

    x1   x2   x3   x4   x5 count_yes
1  yes   no <NA>   no <NA>         1
2   no  yes <NA>  yes   no         2
3 <NA>   no <NA>   no   no         0
4  yes <NA>  yes   no   no         2
5  yes   no  yes   no   no         2
6  yes  yes  yes   no <NA>         3
7 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>         0
8   no <NA>  yes   no   no         1
```

Comment: This is looking promising. Just one quick thing, due to the nature of my variable names, when using across function, could I use "ends_with" rather than "starts_with"?

Comment: Yes. Take a look [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) to know all the functions you can use inside across

Answer (score 1):

in Base R:

```
cbind(have, count_yes = rowSums(have == 'yes', na.rm=TRUE))

    x1   x2   x3   x4   x5 count_yes
1  yes   no <NA>   no <NA>         1
2   no  yes <NA>  yes   no         2
3 <NA>   no <NA>   no   no         0
4  yes <NA>  yes   no   no         2
5  yes   no  yes   no   no         2
6  yes  yes  yes   no <NA>         3
7 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>         0
8   no <NA>  yes   no   no         1
```

if only interested in those that starts with `x`:

```
rowSums(have[startsWith(names(have), 'x')] == 'yes', na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 1 2 0 2 2 3 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another R base solution, using `transform` the R base inspiration for dplyr's `mutate`

```
> transform(have, count_yes = rowSums(have == 'yes', na.rm=TRUE))
    x1   x2   x3   x4   x5 count_yes
1  yes   no <NA>   no <NA>         1
2   no  yes <NA>  yes   no         2
3 <NA>   no <NA>   no   no         0
4  yes <NA>  yes   no   no         2
5  yes   no  yes   no   no         2
6  yes  yes  yes   no <NA>         3
7 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>         0
8   no <NA>  yes   no   no         1
```

Answer (score 0):

We may also do

```
 have$count_yes <- rowSums(have == "yes", na.rm = TRUE)
```

-output

```
 have
    x1   x2   x3   x4   x5 count_yes
1  yes   no <NA>   no <NA>         1
2   no  yes <NA>  yes   no         2
3 <NA>   no <NA>   no   no         0
4  yes <NA>  yes   no   no         2
5  yes   no  yes   no   no         2
6  yes  yes  yes   no <NA>         3
7 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>         0
8   no <NA>  yes   no   no         1
```